# stuck with first steps with py2app on os x with ActivePython

Tags: python, macos, py2app, activepython, pypm

I have a simple python program I want to turn into an app.
py2app is what I need, according to my research.

I'm using ActivePython 2.7 on OS X (snow leopard). 
via the [PyPM tool](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/py2app/) (package manager) I have installed a package called py2app.

The documentation for py2app has a tutorial page http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html#id7

It says I should be able to do this as a first step:

```
py2applet --make-setup MyApplication.py
```

but I have no such executable anywhere that I can find. I thought this would have been installed by the package.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this command:

```
$ pypm files py2app | grep py2applet
~/Library/Python/2.7/bin/py2applet 
~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/py2app/script_py2applet.py 
$
```

So, do you have `~/Library/Python/2.7/bin/py2applet`?

You can also add `~/Library/Python/2.7/bin/` to your `$PATH` (in `~/.profile`) - which PyPM tries to do on first run.